# Finding basis for the space spanned by some vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a subset of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$ that forms the basis for the space spanned by these vectors: $$v1=\left ( \begin{array}{c} 1\\-2\\0\\3 \end{array}\right), v2= \left ( \begin{array}{c} 2\\-5\\-3\\6\end{array}\right)\, ,\, v3=\left ( \begin{array}{c}1\\-1\\3\\1\end{array} \right)\, ,\, v4=\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\-1\\4\\-7\end{array} \right )\, ,\, v5=\left (\begin{array}{c}3\\2\\14\\-17\end{array} \right).$$

Comment: Take as many vectors as you can while remaining linearly independent. This is your basis and the number of vectors you picked is the dimension of your subspace.

Comment: As, at most 4 vectors among these can be linearly independent, Do I need to proceed through combinatorial approach? Or is there any particular procedure to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to guess; just write down the matrix having the vectors as columns:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
-2 & -5 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & -3 & 3 & 4 &  14  \\
3 & 6 & 1 & -7 &  -17
\end{bmatrix}$$
and proceed with Gaussian elimination; first do $R_2+2R_1$ (sum to the second row the first multiplied by $2$) and then $R_4+(-3)R_1$ to get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 3 & 8 \\
0 & -3 & 3 & 4 &  14  \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -13 &  -24
\end{bmatrix}$$
I usually do pivot reduction, so multiply the second row by $-1$ and then do $R_3+3R_2$ to get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & -8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -5 &  -10  \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -13 &  -24
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now swap the third and fourth rows; if you also do pivot reduction you get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & -8 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 13/2 &  12 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  2  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since we have pivots in the first four columns, we conclude that $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ span your subspace. But, of course, since the dimension of the subspace is $4$, it is the whole $\mathbb{R}^4$, so any basis of the space would do.

These computations are surely easier than computing the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix. Note that if the dimension of the subspace were less than $4$, computing a determinant built with any set of four vectors would lead to nothing, while the elimination *always* works.

Answer (score 1):

We know the dimension of the space is at most $4$.  So, let's guess $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ form a basis of the space.  To verify that this guess is correct, it is sufficient to check that
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -5 & -3 & 6 \\
1 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & 4 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0.$$
If this turns out to be true, since the matrix has non-zero determinant, the rows are linearly independent and thus span a $4$-dimensional space (which must be the whole space).